# Python re.sub considered slow?

Tags: python, regex, string

I am fairly new to Python. I am building a script to grovel through a log file, like I have done a hundred times in Perl. I am using a hash to count occurrences of certain fields in the log file, like I have done a hundred time in Perl, a-la:

```
for $line in (<FILE>) {
    ($stuff1, $stuff2, $etc) = split(/\s+/, $line);
    $stuff1 =~ s/something//;
    $stuff2 =~ s/something//;
    $count1{$stuff1}++;
    $count2{$stuff2}++;
}
etc, print the hashes
```

My Python looks like this:

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

cntdaemon = defaultdict(int)
cntfaclevel = defaultdict(int)
cnthost = defaultdict(int)
redaemon1 = re.compile('\[[0-9]+\]')
redaemon2= re.compile(':')
refaclevel= re.compile(']')
with open("/var/adm/messages", 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        (m, d, t, host, daemon, junk, idno, faclevel, text) = line.split(' ',8)
        daemon = re.sub(redaemon1, '', daemon)
        daemon = re.sub(redaemon2, '', daemon)
        cntdaemon[daemon] += 1
        faclevel = re.sub(refaclevel, '', faclevel)
        cntfaclevel[faclevel] += 1
        cnthost[host] += 1
print cntdaemon
print cntfaclevel
print cnthost
```

I'm finding this runs about 20 times slower than the Perl version. I've run testcases precompiling the regexps vs. compiling them "on the fly" and there is negligible difference so I know Python isn't wasting time compiling the regexps. My suspicion is it's spending all its time destroying and compiling the strings each time I do a "re.sub".

So, simple question - is there an idiom to do the substitution faster?

I guess I could always try writing a function to do it without the assignment.... is that an approach often taken? One could convert the string to a list and then iter through it, C/C++ string style (well, I'm just throwing that out there...)

This may be important (and is why I don't use a Counter() in the example) - I am required to write this in Python 2.6.4. If this would be a lot faster in 2.7 or 3 just say so. But I don't have a choice.

Comment: The 1 character regexes can be sped up with `str.replace` or `str.translate(None, ':')`

Comment: Indeed, skipping unnecessary `re.sub` calls should speed the script up about three-fold, not to mention the readability benefits. But personally, I'd do this kind of thing in Awk, not Python, if it had to be fast.

Comment: Interesting - I trimmed the syslog fie back I was reading back from about 4,000,000 lines to 20,000 lines and the Python version runs in about the same amount of time as the Perl version. So:

Answer (score 1):

First you should try to profile the running time of each line. Make a short program like this and measure how long it takes to run.

Begin commenting out the lines that don't have other calculations depending on them.

```
line = "blah blah..."     # typical line from the file
for i in range(10000):    # pretend there are 10000 lines
    (m, d, t, host, daemon, junk, idno, faclevel, text) = line.split(' ',8)
    daemon = re.sub(redaemon1, '', daemon)
    daemon = re.sub(redaemon2, '', daemon)
    cntdaemon[daemon] += 1
    faclevel = re.sub(refaclevel, '', faclevel)
    cntfaclevel[faclevel] += 1
#    cnthost[host] += 1
```

Now you can work out how much time `cnthost[host] += 1` takes

```
line = "blah blah..."     # typical line from the file
for i in range(10000):    # pretend there are 10000 lines
    (m, d, t, host, daemon, junk, idno, faclevel, text) = line.split(' ',8)
    daemon = re.sub(redaemon1, '', daemon)
    daemon = re.sub(redaemon2, '', daemon)
    cntdaemon[daemon] += 1
    faclevel = re.sub(refaclevel, '', faclevel)
#    cntfaclevel[faclevel] += 1
#    cnthost[host] += 1        # takes 20 seconds
```

Now you can work out how much time `cntfaclevel[faclevel] += 1` takes

etc.

Once you have worked out the hotspot - then start thinking of ways to make it faster.

If you can add a typical string you are processing to the question, we'll be able to see if there are particular tricks that can be used, or if there is something particular you are doing badly performance wise.

Comment: Well, commenting out the hash[key] =+ 1 lines didn't changes things much. Commenting out the "re" functions one at a time took time off proportional to the number of re operations commented out. So re is definitely a bottleneck, whether it's re.sub() or re.split().
I trimmed the syslog I was reading back from about 4,000,000 lines to 20,000 lines and the Python version runs in about the same amount of time as the Perl version in that scenarios. I'll do some more checks again next week. The str.replace and str.translate suggestions were helpful, and I was just reminded of the "in" keyword.

Comment: @wsanders, I can't help you optimise it more without seeing what the lines look like.